# API's JSONRpcClient call from Google Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, json-rpc

I have the mission to connect the data from a web app called [simplybook.me](https://simplybook.me/en/) using its API with some google sheets.

Right now, I need to know how to execute or parse the next snippet inside Google Sheets’ script so I can get the access token (which is the first step to achieve my goal).

```
//javascript
var loginClient = new JSONRpcClient({
    'url': 'https://user-api.simplybook.me/login',
    'onerror': function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
var token = loginClient.getToken('{companyLogin}', '{apiKey}');
```

So my questions are: **Is it possible to make this kind of call from a Google Script? If it's only possible using javascript, How can I embed that inside a Google Script? If you think there's a better way, Can you depict it?**

Note 1: I got the snippet from the [API Explorer](https://simplybook.me/en/api/developer-api/tab/explorer_api), where the result is outputted effortlessly, but when trying to migrate it my first problem was how to call JSONRpcClient from Google Scripts.

Note 2: I was looking for a solution and I got this [repo](https://github.com/michalliu/google-app-script-jsonrpc/blob/master/libjsonrpc.gs), but still don’t know what to do with it.

Also, point me out the road to follow (what do I have to learn) to get this done.

Comment: Hi there @AntonioGraterol! I understand that you want to replicate that code behaviour into [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). To better help you, could you please clarify what is your end goal with that code?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron thanks for replying. My goal is to be able to update (via API) several Google spreadsheets with the booking and paying data gathered by this app. Right now the population of the sheets is been done manually... I'm getting deeper into javascript to understand how it works, but my goal is to equip a google script with a routine to fetch all the information needed

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the Sheets API with JavaScript (or some other language), you could do so by following the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). There you will find working examples and tutorials to set up the project. Then you only need to include a [`spreadsheet.values.update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) to append a row to the desired Sheet. Please take a look and write back if you have any doubt.

Comment: I'll definitely check that guide. In the text I've mentioned that someone made a Jsonrpcclient implementation inside Google sheets and I still think that's the way to go solve this thread, though I find my way out of that using the Rest API shown in the website documentation, so I pulled this out. Thanks for the advice